# How to match a column and extract values between two files in Shell

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell

I have two csv files with these values

FileA.csv

```
CACHE_1005,VB14314690
CACHE_1071,VB69700608
CACHE_1211,VB85967916
```

FileB.csv

```
CACHE_1005,unk,HS2000-785_105^1
CACHE_1005,unk,HS2000-785_105^2
CACHE_1005,unk,HS2000-899_107^2
CACHE_1005,unk,HS2000-901_127^1
CACHE_1071,unk,HS2000-152_566^1
CACHE_1071,unk,HS2000-940_103^7
CACHE_1071,unk,HS2000-940_103^8
CACHE_1211,unk,HS2000-152_566^2
CACHE_1211,unk,HS2000-152_566^3
CACHE_1211,unk,HS2000-152_566^4
```

I want to match first columns in two csv files and extract values of second column in FileA and append to FileB. This is the result I want:

Result.csv

```
CACHE_1005,unk,HS2000-785_105^1,VB14314690
CACHE_1005,unk,HS2000-785_105^2,VB14314690
CACHE_1005,unk,HS2000-899_107^2,VB14314690
CACHE_1005,unk,HS2000-901_127^1,VB14314690
CACHE_1071,unk,HS2000-152_566^1,VB69700608
CACHE_1071,unk,HS2000-940_103^7,VB69700608
CACHE_1071,unk,HS2000-940_103^8,VB69700608
CACHE_1211,unk,HS2000-152_566^2,VB85967916
CACHE_1211,unk,HS2000-152_566^3,VB85967916
CACHE_1211,unk,HS2000-152_566^4,VB85967916
```

Comment: How many records are there to match in both files? Awk may be able to manage this with moderate size files, or your samples. For larger dataset, it may be more appropriate to convert the CSV into SQLite3 data tables and run an SQL query on it.

Comment: @LéaGris Only need to match 1st column and append the second column values of FileA.csv onto FileB.csv.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is exactly what the `join` command is doing.

```sh
> join -t, fileB.csv fileA.csv 
CACHE_1005,unk,HS2000-785_105^1,VB14314690
CACHE_1005,unk,HS2000-785_105^2,VB14314690
CACHE_1005,unk,HS2000-899_107^2,VB14314690
CACHE_1005,unk,HS2000-901_127^1,VB14314690
CACHE_1071,unk,HS2000-152_566^1,VB69700608
CACHE_1071,unk,HS2000-940_103^7,VB69700608
CACHE_1071,unk,HS2000-940_103^8,VB69700608
CACHE_1211,unk,HS2000-152_566^2,VB85967916
CACHE_1211,unk,HS2000-152_566^3,VB85967916
CACHE_1211,unk,HS2000-152_566^4,VB85967916
```

`-t` sets the separator, also files have to be sorted like in your example, if not, you can `join <(sort file2) <(sort file1)` without preserving the order, or give a try with `--nocheck-order`.

Note: assuming you have a simple csv file, like in your example, without nested separators inside quoted fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can read fileA (by `while read line` or `for` loop) each line and use `sed` command to append column 2 to fileB:

```
#!/bin/bash
for lineA in $(cat FileA.csv); do
        pattern=${lineA%,*}
        extract=${lineA#*,}
        sed -i "/$pattern/s/$/\,$extract/g" FileB.csv
done
```